# End of file in string in R

Tags: r, csv

I want to read a `.csv` file that contains `;` and  `\` characters. This causes the reading of file to fail. I can overcome this problem by specifying the `quote = ""` argument in the `read.csv` command - however, this will prefix all my column names with `x.`

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't answer this question, but if you provide your current code, input, current output and _expected_ output, you will have a higher chance of getting an answer.

Comment: (PS: edit your question with those details, don't post it as comments)

Comment: Please show a few lines of the file